# usar javascript para cambiar una imagen html

Tags: javascript, html, clase, li

Tengo un motor de reserva que me gestiona las entradas. Éste se encuentra en otro servidor al cuál no tengo acceso y quiero cambiar código html de una de las partes del motor. Estoy intentando cambiar la imagen y otras partes del motor.

Lo que tengo entendido que podría usar Javascript para poder reemplazar la imagen. Pero no encuentro id de esta. He intentado cambiar la imagen por su clase. Pero tampoco me sale. Este es el código html:

```html
<div class="eventsCalendar-subtitle" style="height: 2em;">

<img class="arrow-select-hour" src="/img/arrow-select-hour.png?20161020" style="height: 30px;">

<span class="arrow-select-hour">Elige hora</span></div>
```

Y aquí el código java con el que intento modificar la imagen:

```
<script>
var arrow-select-hour = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-select-hour");
document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-select-hour").innerHTML = "url(https://i.ibb.co/xD1c5PY/flecha3.png)";
</script>
```

Lo mismo pasa con la etiqueta li. [Aquí](https://i.ibb.co/Xsv9WwR/1.jpg) la imagen

---

Lo he dejado así:

```html
<script>
document.getElementByClassName("arrow-select-hour").src="https://i.ibb.co/xD1c5PY/flecha3.png";
</script>
```

y no me ha dado resultados. Algo mal estoy haciendo?

Answer (score 2):

El atributo que debés usar para reemplazar la imagen es `.src`

Adicionalmente, la función `getElementsByClassName` retorna un arreglo de elementos, por lo que tendrás que seleccionar el primer elemento del arreglo para hacer el cambio.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("arrow-select-hour")[0].src = "https://i.ibb.co/xD1c5PY/flecha3.png";
```

Answer (score 1):

para poder cambiar la imagen mediante javascript debes actualizar el atributo src de esta forma

```
document.getElementByClassName("arrow-select-hour")[0].src="https://i.ibb.co/xD1c5PY/flecha3.png";
```

si no se te refresca la nueva imagen puedes pasar un timestamp para forzar que aparezca la nueva imagen

espero que te ayude con la solucion

saludos